# Textbox showing only 1 word out of database instead of whole sentence

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys I have a code that selects out of my database and puts it into the textbox. Yet it only shows 1 word instead of the whole sentence.

this is my code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){

echo '<form action="details.php?ID='.$row['ID'].'" method="post">';
echo "<tr>";
echo '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$row['ID'].'">';
echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=title value=" . $row['Title'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text size=45 name=detail value=" . $row['Detail'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['eventDate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['dateAdded'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=delete" . " </td>";
```

I hope someone knows the answer because i've been stuck for like 1 hour and can't seem to find the answer. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Check the source to see the raw HTML. You aren't closing your input tags btw.

Comment: Does your value contain breaks?

Comment: i am not so sure but i saw an attribute `size=45` so maybe this is limiting your data

Comment: 'View Source ..." is your friend.

Comment: Thank you but the answer is below I'm gonna accept it soon. But santa's it has nothing to do with size but still thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to close input all inputs should be closed properly.

```
echo '<td>' . '<input type="text" name="title" value="' . $row['Title'] . '">'.'</td>';
```

Also

```
echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . '<input type="text" size="45" name="detail" value="'.$row['Detail'].'"></td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['eventDate'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['dateAdded'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . '<input type="submit" name="update" value="update"> ' . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . '<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"> ' . '</td>';
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough man! Not only did you solve my problem you fixed the whole code for me aswell! big props to you my friend!